# warning message/pop out for date/time

Tags: java, javascript, jsf

I have a form where a user need to enter date and time (2 different fields) and the time cannot be more than 12 hours old. So I want to add a warning message (most likely a pop-up alert) when the time is older than 12 hours. I am using JSF and Java. Please help me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script language="JavaScript">
  function validate()
  {
    var dateEntered = new Date( document.getElementById("Date") + " " + document.getElementById("Time") );
    var dateNow = new Date();

    if( dateNow - dateEntered > 1000*60*60*12 )
    {
      alert( "Date entered is too old." );
      return( false );
    }
    return( true );
  }
</script>

<form method=post action="blah.html" onsubmit="JavaScript: return( validate() );">
  <input type=text id=Date name=Date>
  <input type=text id=Time name=Time>
  <input type=submit value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: how do I use this function? I am using h:inputText to enter the date and time.Thanks

Comment: I made some edits to my post. Since you didn't give many details I can't help you more than that.

Comment: <h:inputText value="#{Date}" required="true" id="date" >
  <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy"/>                     </h:inputText>                      For the date field before I use the validation I have the above codes and the same for the time field as well

Comment: Was there a question? I don't understand what you're typing there since it's not HTML/JavaScript. What I've given you should work.