# warning to avoid time in future in Java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [warning message/pop out for date/time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650753/warning-message-pop-out-for-date-time)

I have a form where a user need to enter date and time (2 different fields) and the time cannot be in future. It can either be current time or time in past only to 12 hours before. So I want to add a warning message when the time is older than 12 hours. How will be the calculation of this in Java. Please help me out!

Comment: Duplicate of [warning message/pop out for date/time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650753/warning-message-pop-out-for-date-time). If the answers doesn't satisfy you, rather use `edit` link to improve the original question (add more detail, add/remove (ir)relevant tags, etc) instead of pressing `Ask Question` to post a duplicate. I suspect that using the `[javascript]` tag was a wrong choice.

Comment: Is this a Java question/problem or JavaScript?  You shouldn't have both tags here.

Comment: @BalusC thanks for the suggestion, this is a different problem where I need help to prevent typing time in future and need that in Java and not Javascript/JSF

Comment: the same answer with little modification won't work ?

Comment: I will remember that from now, Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

If you want Java this should work. JODA is good, but it is another lib dependency.

`   import java.util.Calendar;
   import junit.framework.TestCase;
   import static java.lang.System.out;

public class DateCheck extends TestCase {
    public void testCheckBefore(){
        //Gets the current time
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

```
    //Let's make it 13:00 just to make the example simple.
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 13);
    out.println(c.getTime());

    Calendar old = Calendar.getInstance();
    old.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    if(old.after(c)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("You entered a date in the future");
    }

    assertTrue(olderThanTwelveHours(c, old));

    // Let's change to 5 in the morning.
    old.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 5);
    assertFalse(olderThanTwelveHours(c, old));
}

private boolean olderThanTwelveHours(Calendar c, Calendar old) {
    long startTime= c.getTimeInMillis();
    long oldTime = old.getTimeInMillis();

    long timeDiff = startTime - oldTime;
    if(timeDiff > (12 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) {
        out.println("You're too late");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}`

Comment: To clarify `12 * 60 * 60 * 1000` this means 12 hours times 60 minutes per hour times 60 seconds per minute times 1000 milliseconds per second.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically wanting to calculate the hours difference between 2 dates. You can easily do that using JodaTime [hoursBetween](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Hours.html#hoursBetween%28org.joda.time.ReadableInstant,%20org.joda.time.ReadableInstant%29) method.